# Updating Page Metadata In XPM

Tags: experience-manager, web8

We're using XPM to edit the page metadata.

Once we hit 'Save and Close' the 'Update preview' button is enabled to show that changes have been made, which we can perform, but we're finding it difficult to the save the page as 'Cancel Editing' and 'Finish Editing' are not enabled.

If we leave XPM, there's no warning that changes have been made / do we wish to publish etc.

This is a different workflow for editing components, in that we can check out the page, make edits, save them (which is auto published) etc.

I'm tempted to write a GUI ext to prompt the user to publish, but i'm wondering if anyone has noticed this behaviour and has other work arounds to make the experience similar for content editors.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some debugging on my Web 8 instance regarding this subject and found the following happens when saving page metadata through XPM

- When clicking the save button in the edit metadata popup, a save action is triggered
- the IsEnabled function for the Finish editing button is also triggered, and is set to true, as it finds that one item has been changed (the page metadata we just edited)
- the save action is performed, and Tridion has saved the page metadata and Tridion also publishes the changed page to the session preview webservice
- the IsEnabled function for the Finish editing button is triggered again, and now it returns false, as there are no more changed items (as the page has already been saved).

The issue here is that, normally, when you click 'finish editing', Fast Track Publishing starts and publishes the page to staging as well (so not just to the session preview webservice). This means that, in order to get the page metadata changes published, you will have to press the publish button in XPM manually.

Strangely enough, in Tridion 2013 (SP1), the Finish editing button does appear after editing metadata. I wonder if this is a bug in Web 8 ?

Answer (score 0):

A GUI extension would be nice, but that comes with the burden of having to maintain it and keep it functioning after upgrades (I.e. regression testing and fixing).

My standard approach to this kind of item is to build-in emphasis on it when conducting editor training and plan some support time specifically around XPM user adoption.